# Dash app auto update with dcc.Interval not working

Tags: python-3.x, callback, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am trying to get my dash dashboard to auto update using Dcc.Interval and Callbacks. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. The html.P component "children" are not updating and it doesn't seem like the Interval is bein initiated:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
# Previous day column
dbc.Col([html.H1(PREV_DAY,
                 style={'textAlign': 'center', 'height': '5%', 'margin-top': '30px', 'margin-bottom': '25px',
                        'font-family': 'Consolas', 'font-size': 'xxx-large'}),
         dbc.Card(
             [
                 dbc.CardBody(
                     [
                        html.H4(id='card_title_1', children=['Sales'], className='card-title'),
                        html.P(id='card_text_1', children=['Sample text.']),
                        dcc.Interval(
                             id='interval-component',
                             interval=10 * 1000,  # in milliseconds
                             n_intervals=0
                         )
                     ], style={'textAlign': 'center', 'font-family': 'Consolas'}
                 )
             ], style={'margin-top': '15px', 'margin-bottom': '15px', 'height': '30%'}
         ),
```

I am trying to update the html.P(id='card_text_1') element with each interval. Here is my callbacks:

```
### SECTION - Callbacks ###
@app.callback(
    Output('card_text_1', 'children'),
    Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))

def update_metrics(n):
    salesYest = 'test'
    return [{}.format(salesYest)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the console where you run the app you will see this error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'

The problem is this part in your callback

```
return [{}.format(salesYest)]
```

As the error says a dictionary doesn't have an attribute `format`.

Now I'm not really sure what you're trying to do exactly in the callback, but the `Interval` component itself is working fine. You  can test this by changing your callback to something like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("card_text_1", "children"), Input("interval-component", "n_intervals")
)
def update_metrics(n):
    return n
```

Also keep in mind that you have set the `interval` to `10000` milliseconds. So be sure to check if `10` seconds have actually passed in case it still seems it isn't doing anything or lower the `interval` when debugging.

Also aside from the format issue you're currently returning the same value every time so you wouldn't notice anything either way.

Comment: Ok, I see the callback is working properly. Strange that I do not see the Attribute error when I run app.py in PyCharm. I was originally trying to send the results of a SQL query through the callback: 
    `def update_metrics(n):`
        `salesYest = salesYest()`
        `return [salesYest]`
and I thought maybe the return had to be in string format so I was trying to do that. Any insight into how to display the errors in PyCharm?

Comment: @fryman84 You can set `debug=True` as a parameter to `run_server` then callback related errors should show up clearly inside the browser. Even when debug is set to `False` you will probably still see errors in the browser console. Presumably you should also see it in the integrated terminal inside PyCharm, but I don't use PyCharm so that's just guessing.

Comment: My original error was referencing a function outside of the callback. I placed the function inside of the callback and it work perfectly.

Comment: `children` doesn't need to have a string returned by the way. It also works with number, a single component, or a list of components https://community.plotly.com/t/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-children-property-and-where-to-get-the-property-list/7336/2